# libreOffice calc prefixes the name of the sheet into all the cells that are an equation

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, prefix

LibreOffice calc prefixes the name of the sheet into all the cells that are an equation.
This is really annoying. Not only it makes the size of the spreadsheet enormous, but if I want to make a copy of a sheet into another (as a model to my next sheet), either it uses all the values from the original  sheet, or I have to remove all these prefixes (that will reappear again as soon as I save and reload the spreadsheet), before I make a copy.
This process should take me a second to do, but instead it takes me hours on a large sheet.
Why is it doing this anyway, and how can I prevent it from happening, or alternatively, how do I remove these prefixes in every cell all at once?

Comment: I have done some simple tests, and I can't reproduce this (LO 6.0.3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1). You can remove all instances of (for instance) `Sheet1.` in a single operation with `Replace All` in the `Find & Replace` function (`Ctrl+H`). Other options allow you to replace in the whole document or the current selection.

Comment: What you describe isn't normal behavior for cell or range references on the same worksheet.  Either something is corrupt, or something about the spreadsheet or settings is causing it.  There isn't really enough information to diagnose the cause.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how or when it happened.
All I know is that I have been using calc for quite a while, and I have removed these prefixes containing the name of the sheet something like :
Cell A4: =$'sheet1'.A2+$'sheet1'.A1
when I originally set A4 to =A2+A1  (for example).
and I keep removing  them, and they have seemed to periodically reappear.
I don't know how or why.

Comment: On one of the spreadsheet I use, I recently removed all the prefixes in one sheet so I could make a duplicate of it unto another sheet, and was kinda expecting these to reappear, but they haven't yet.
It is possible that it is an old bug that is now fixed.. again I don't know.

Comment: Or it is possible that there is something that triggers these prefixes to be inserted, and I haven't done what triggers it in my last changes...
Sorry I can't help you more, for now, Would it be possible to look at the code to see where there is code to do that, and what can make this code be executed by mistake?